# Finding mapping between two spatial representations of the same objects

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, na.numerical-analysis

I have two matrices $U$ and $V$.  $U$ is $n \times n$ and $V$ is $n \times m$. (Both are empirical results of an experiment.) I would like to find a linear transformation $A$, $m \times n$, such that $VA = \hat{U}$, where $\hat{U} = \underset{X}{\arg \min}$ $m(X, U)$ for some metric $m$.

Is there a closed form or iterative solution to this problem?

Comment: What is the argmin taken over? If it is taken over all n x n matrices, then $\hat{U} = U$, so presumably you are imagining taking the argmin over a different set. What this set is and what  the metric is seem potentially crucial to an answer.

Comment: Your formulation implies that any linear transformation A is acceptable to you as long as the product VA is close to U, but are you sure of this?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow even if the argmin is over all $n\times n$ matrices, it's not clear that it's possible to get $U$, so the question is still well defined (the implicit restriction on X is that it's the image of f(A) = VA)

Comment: @Suresh: That is what I first thought, but it is not correct.  Note that if the argmin is really over all n×n matrices, then it has nothing to do with the product VA!

Comment: Right. So X has to be restricted to matrices that can be formed as VA for a fixed V

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your error norm is the Frobenius distance (that is, $m(X, U) = \|X - U \|_F$, then there is a closed form for your problem. $A = V^+ U$, where $V^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $V$ (this is a generalized inverse for non-square matrices).

Comment: Thanks. This is great. I'm curious whether there is a closed form solution if (1) we take $m$ to be the Schatten $p$-norm of $X - U$ for any $p$ (not just the Frobenius, where $p = 2$); or (2) we take $m$ to be the 2-norm--i.e. the spectral radius of $X - U$. If there is a solution for (2), I wonder whether it is general for a matrix norm induced by a vector $p$-norm for any $p$.

Comment: It's a good question. Not sure I know the answer :)